# If a function doesn't have Laurent series can we still determine the singularity type?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Laurent series at $z = 0$.
I have the following two functions: $f(z) = z^{\frac{2}{3}}$ and $f(z) = (z+1)^{-\frac{4}{3}}$.

For the first one I used Taylor's theorem and there is no Laurent series for the first one. It's simply $z^{\frac{2}{3}}$. Can I just say since the negative part of the Laurent series is $0$ it's removable singularity. For the second one: $$ f(z) = 1 - \frac{4}{3}z + \frac{14}{9}z^2 - \cdots$$
It's just essential singularity .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first one has an algebraic singularity (branch point) at $z=0$, the second one is analytic at $z=0$.

Comment: The classification of singularities into removable, poles and essential only make sense for functions with *isolated singularities*, i.e. you want your function to be holomorphic on a punctured neighbourhood of the singularity. Your two examples don't have isolated singularities (at $z=0$ and $z=-1$, respectively).

Answer (score 1):

If the Laurent series is a Taylor series, you have a removable singularity (ie you can define the function f at z_0 to be analytic).

If the Laurent series has finitely many negative powers of (z-z_0), then it is a pole (at z_0). This is because we can write a function f as f(z) = g(z)/(z-z_0)^m, where g is analytic at z_0, g(z_0) is not 0, and m is the order of the pole.

Otherwise, it is an essential singularity.

Comment: Is it right what I'm saying then for the first one? Is it removable?

Comment: Are you sure the Laurent Series is 0? Taylor’s theorem says the coefficients a_n = f^(n)(z_0) / n! . a_0 is 0 but for other a_i, you have f^(n)(z_0) = 1/0